# which TLD for forwarding nameserver?

Tags: nameserver, powerdns, dns-server, tld

I want to setup 2 forwarding name servers with powerdns for customer sites.

My question is if it matters the domain under which the name servers will be registered.

Godaddy panel - for what I recall - has a check box that declares the domain as a name server followed by the name we want to assign.

Suppose I buy `example.xyz` and assign nameserver `ns1.example.xyz`. 
Will I have any problem compared with a registered name `example.com` and nameserver `ns1.example.com`?

If you disagree with the process don't hesitate to write your opinion.

Thank you.

PS: my question is about 2 nameservers based on 2 different TLDs and if one is preferred over the other & NOT about how a client domain sees a nameserver. I suppose [this](https://gr.godaddy.com/help/add-my-own-host-names-as-nameservers-12320) article is the right process.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter because `example.xyz` and `example.com` are totally different domain names. DNS resolving starts from top domain name zone (from the end), from `xyz.` and `com.`, not from `example.`.

Comment: would it matter in terms of efficiency the .com over .xyz??

Comment: suppose both servers have powerdns installed...

Comment: Only in the terms of marketing, not from technical point of view.